# Are there algorithms related to cloud shapes?

Tags: random, 3d

This is going to be applied in programming, but I thought the question would be best answered here, since I'm just looking for algorithms at the moment. I'm generating clouds on the fly, but I'm not really sure how to make them look like actual cloud shapes without predefining said shapes. I know there are quite a few different types of clouds, but I wasn't really able to find any cloud formation algorithms.

Comment: You might look into physical models of cloud formation and see what you can learn from those.

Comment: There is this popular algorithm invented by a computer scientist / mathematician in New York, although I seem to have forgotten his name ( = name of algorithm ). It's been very famous since the 80s. Ah. Ken Perlin was his name. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlin_noise <-- here is a wikipedia article about Perlin Noise.